# How do I make my VS Code dev/remote container port accessible to localhost?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, graphql

I have a GraphQL application that run inside a container. If I run `docker compose build` followed by `docker compose up` I can connect to it via `localhost:9999/graphql`. Inside the dockerfile the port forwarding is `9999:80`. When I run the `docker container ls` command I can see the ports are forewarded as expected.
I'd like to running this in a VS Code remote container. Selecting `Open folder in remote container` gives me the option of selecting either the dockerfile or the docker-compose file to build the container. I've tried both options and neither allows me to access the GraphQL playground from localhost. Running from docker-compose I can see that the ports appear to be forwarded in the same manner as if I ran `docker compose up` but I can't access the site.
Where am I going wrong?

Update: If I run `docker compose up` on the container that is built by vs code, I can connect to localhost and the graphql playground.

```
FROM docker.removed.local/node
MAINTAINER removed

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY package.json /opt/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /opt/app/package-lock.json
COPY .npmrc /opt/app/.npmrc
RUN echo "nameserver 192.168.11.1" > /etc/resolv.conf && npm ci
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/logs

# Setup a path for using local npm packages
RUN mkdir -p /opt/node_modules

ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY ./ /opt/app
EXPOSE 80

ENV NODE_PATH /opt:/opt/app:$NODE_PATH
ARG NODE_ENV

VOLUME ["/opt/app"]

CMD ["forever", "-o", "/opt/app/logs/logs.log", "-e", "/opt/app/logs/error.log", "-a", "server.js"]

version: '3.5'
services:
  server:
      build: .
      container_name: removed-data-graph
      command: nodemon --ignore 'public/*' --legacy-watch src/server.js
      image: docker.removed.local/removed-data-graph:local
      ports:
          - "9999:80"
      volumes:
          - .:/opt/app
          - /opt/app/node_modules/
            #- ${LOCAL_PACKAGE_DIR}:/opt/node_modules
      depends_on:
          - redis
      networks:
          - company-network
      environment:
          - NODE_ENV=dev
  redis:
      container_name: redis
      image: redis
      networks:
          - company-network
      ports:
          - "6379:6379"
networks:
    company-network:
        name: company-network
```

Comment: Can you post the dockerfile and compose yml?

Comment: @SergioSantiago files added

Comment: You definitely need to use the `docker-compose` in VSCode, because the graphql depends on redis container. Is there any log when VSCode tries to run the docker-compose? What is the output for `docker ps` when VSCode runs your `docker-compose`?

Comment: i selected docker-compose from the options when selecting open in container. i then selected server. docker ps shows exactly the same info as if I had used docker container start command

Comment: this is the output when it starts the VS Code server:
[84518 ms] Start: Run: docker exec -i -u root -e VSCODE_REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SESSION=2befbbb1-9c08-4bd3-920f-3649df4cf5831594128703588 324f9e1473628d4553f35f6c54a4ff54dbeda38ae34439e88df3a42418ead6a3 /root/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/e95f9e63380a139cb1cbe54bacfc6703b96e30b9/node -e

Comment: There are certain networking operations that do not occur until `up` is called. VSCode may be running the container without `--service-ports`, which is what exposes those port mappings (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)

Comment: is it possible to work around that or get VS Code to use that option?